# Scope of a variable declared inside a for- loop

Tags: java, variables, scope

In the example below, variable `count` is ignored by java if it's declared inside the `for` loop. If it is declared inside the method `isPrime()` instead, everything goes well.

I don't understand why?

Here is my code.

```
public class Interest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        isPrime();

    }

    static void isPrime() {

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {

            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("The number is: " + i);
                System.out.println("We have: " + count + " prime numbers");
                if (count == 10) {
                    System.out.println("The loop is ending");
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Because the `for` loop has its own scope, thus the variable is defined only in the loop. Rule of thumb : everything defined inside `{   }` is local to the section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is how `java` works. If you declare a variable in a block then that block is the scope of the variable.

Quoting from [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

A `for` implies a scope, so the scope of count is restricted to that block (it means it is a local block variable).

Moreover, you see it as `java` looks like it is ignoring any update on `count` because at each iteration the variable gets re-initialized.
You can see it a little better printing `count` at the start and at the end of each iteration.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
     int count = 0;
      System.out.println("Begin " + count );
      if (i % 2 != 0) 
         count++;
     System.out.println("End " + count );
}
```

Produces:

```
Begin 0
End   1
Begin 0
End   0
Begin 0
End   1
Begin 0
End   0
Begin 0
End   1
Begin 0
End   0
Begin 0
End   1
Begin 0
End   0
Begin 0
End   1
....
```

This tells you that whatever update on `count` is lost as soon the control of the function reaches the end of the `for` block. That is why if you want to keep information across iterations you have to use a  variable declared in some outer scope (in this case the scope of the function `isPrime()` works just fine).

Comment: Yes, exactly that happens. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is logic to find odd numbers not prime numbers. Secondly When you put count inside for loop it is reset to 0 every time with increment in i.

The loop terminates when i > more than 50, i.e 51.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Lakshay Gupta

Comment: If it is initialized to zero or not depends on how the variable is declared. It can be like `int count = -123` and at each iteration, it gets initialized with `-123` and not `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the variable with in the loop, the variable's value will be reset for each iteration. That's the reason why you are feeling that "count" is ignored if it's declared inside the loop and some value is printed if it's declared outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.